# Sentiment Analysis- Airbnb

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-transformation, dataset, sentiment-analysis

Are there specific packages in R to do sentiment analysis? I have public reviews of airbnb Seattle here (http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html) and I am intersted in seeing the positive, negative and neutral scores of every review received.

New to Data Science. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sentiment library in R is now obsolete. Even if you get that package from the CRAN archive, it would look hassle free until you deploy the code in Shiny. If you are about to use Shiny too in your work, I recommend you to do the following:

1. Unzip the sentiment package file
2. Get whatever R script available there and deploy the code to the file you are working.
3. Place the dependent files (like .CSV in the sentiment package) to your present working directory.

Now your code would be hassle free.

I also suggest you to use ‘e1071’ package for sentiment computation. This package is more inclined to strong ML concepts than being generic like the ‘sentiment’ package as it only uses 'Naive Bayes Classifier' which won't produce more accuracy.

A thumps up if you liked my answer! :)
good luck, welcome to the new field!